# Obtaining data from a file Json

Tags: java, json

I have a problem extracting data in json filed.In total there are a lot of similar questions but none of them helped me.Me json look this

```
{
    "miasta" : ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
    "drogi" : [
        {
            "miasta" : ["A", "B"],
            "czas_przejazdu" : 2
        },
        {
            "miasta" : ["A", "C"],
            "czas_przejazdu" : 3
        },
        {
            "miasta" : ["A", "D"],
            "czas_przejazdu" : 4
        },
        {
            "miasta" : ["A", "E"],
            "czas_przejazdu" : 1
        }
    ],
    "timeout" : 5,
    "max_czas_przejazdu" : 10
}
```

I tried different methods, but I did not get all the data.This is my current code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException, IOException {
     JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
     JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Laptop\\Desktop\\in.json"));

     for (Object o : a)
     {
         JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

         String name = (String) person.get("miasta");
         System.out.println(name);

         JSONArray drogi = (JSONArray) person.get("drogi");

         for (Object c : drogi)
         {
             System.out.println(c+"");
         }
         String job = (String) person.get("czas_przejazdu");
         System.out.println(job);
     }
 }
```

And the error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
>     at zadanie.

Comment: This error helps you narrow down your issue - org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

You are trying to cast a `JSONObject` to `JSONArray`. Shouldn't your variable `a` be a `JSONObject`?

Comment: You're loading the JSON as an array, when it isn't. It's an object.

Answer (score 0):

A JSON object begins and ends with curly braces, ie...

{"name" : "joe", "age" : "29"}

A JSON array begins and ends with square braces, ie...

[ "bill", 29 ]

The JSON you've posted is a JSON object because it begins and ends with curly braces, but it contains JSON array's.  So when iterating over the data, you'll need to cast the arrays where appropriate.

So to begin with, change your JSONArray declaration to,

JSONObject a = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\in.json"));

**UPDATE**

This should work for you.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "in.json"))) {
    StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        jsonBuilder.append(line);
    }


    JSONObject fullJsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonBuilder.toString());
    //System.out.println(fullJsonObject);

    JSONArray mista = (JSONArray) fullJsonObject.get("miasta");
    //System.out.println(mista);

    JSONArray drogi = (JSONArray) fullJsonObject.get("drogi");
    //System.out.println(drogi);

    List<JSONObject> drogi_objects = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<JSONObject> itr = drogi.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        drogi_objects.add( itr.next() );
    }
    //System.out.println(drogi_objects);

    int iteration = 1;
    for(JSONObject element : drogi_objects) {
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Iteration:\t " + iteration);
        System.out.println("Miasta\t: " + element.get("miasta"));
        System.out.println("czas_przejazdu:\t" + element.get("czas_przejazdu"));
        ++iteration;
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I have a question.What to do to save miasta in String nad czas_przejazdu in int ?

Comment: In the code I posted above, each json object that was in the "drogi" array has been put into a List<JSONObject>.  Each object has a "mista" and a "czas_przejazdu".  So to get the mista as a String for any one of the drogi objects, just get the index you want and do...

String miasta = drogi_objects.get(0).get("miasta");

int czas = Integer.parseInt(drogi_objects.get(0).get("czas_przejazdu"));


Just replace the '0' with the index you want.

Answer (score 0):

May I give you an idea? Giving the fact that you are using Jackson (which I highly agree) why don't you create a Java class that matches your json and the use ObjectMapper to map it so you can work with that class easier?

The java class that matches your json object is like this (the annotations are just the lombok library to avoid the boilerplate getter and setter code, but it is not mandatory)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomClass {
    List<String> miasta;
    List<Drogi> drogi;
    Integer timeout;
    Integer max_czas_przejazdu;
}
```

With that class all you need is to use ObjectMapper. Here a test to show it matches the JSON you have posted

```
public class UseOfObjectMapperTest{

    @Test
    public void testSerializer() throws Exception{

        //Read example
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        CustomClass customClass =  objectMapper.readValue(new File("src/test/resources/customclass.json"),CustomClass.class);
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(customClass));

        //Write Example
        CustomClass cc = new CustomClass(
                Arrays.asList("A","B"),
                Arrays.asList(new Drogi(Arrays.asList("C1","D1"), 10),
                        new Drogi(Arrays.asList("C2","D2"),10)),
                15,20);
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(cc));
    }
}
```